# PHP: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I ran into the following error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Time\app\classes\RadioStatus.class.php on line 42` and I couldn't find an answer.

The full error is from line 42 till 45. These lines:

```
    $this->data->setData('stream_status', $this->simpleXML->STREAMSTATUS);
    $this->data->setData('stream_titel', $this->simpleXML->SERVERTITLE);
    $this->data->setData('stream_luisteraars', $this->simpleXML->CURRENTLISTENERS);
    $this->data->setData('stream_huidigNummer', $this->simpleXML->SONGTITLE);
```

The `$this->data` thing is a class, passed through a constructor. This is because I'm using `Depency Injections`. This is how the data class works (pretty basic):

```
class Data
{
    private $data = array();

function __construct()
{
    $this->setData('naam', 'Time');
    $this->setData('slogan', 'The time has come');
}

public function setData($key, $value)
{
    return $this->data[$key] = $value;
}

public function getData($key)
{
    return $this->data[$key];
}
}
```

As you can see, the `setData` function exists. But still, I'm getting those darn errors. Please help me find the problem to these errors, and if more code is needed, please say so.
 EDIT:

The RadioStatus class:

```
class RafioStatus
{

function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, '178.32.13.195:8004/admin.cgi?sid=1&mode=viewxml&page=1');
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:Assembla12');
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt(curl_init(), CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $this->xml = curl_exec(curl_init());
    curl_close(curl_init());

    $this->simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($this->xml);

    $this->setData('stream_status', $this->simpleXML->STREAMSTATUS);
    $this->setData('stream_titel', $this->simpleXML->SERVERTITLE);
    $this->data->setData('stream_luisteraars', $this->simpleXML->CURRENTLISTENERS);
    $this->data->setData('stream_huidigNummer', $this->simpleXML->SONGTITLE);
}
}
```

Comment: `$this -> data` is an array. What were you expecting?

Comment: try `$this->setData('stream_status', $this->simpleXML->STREAMSTATUS);`

Comment: @AresDraguna the `setData` function is in another class. a bit of proper thinking would know your 'answer' would result in an undefined method...

Comment: @George That it would return the value of the requested 'key'... I only save them in an array. Is that wrong?

Comment: =)) I do not have your code in front of me and I presumed that if you are using $this->data you are in the scope so don't judge me based on that ;) further more, this is not an 'answer' this is a comment, which is very different. $this is a var that belongs to a class and points to a property from a class, my dear :)

Comment: @AresDraguna I'm sorry. But my question states: 'The $this->data thing is a class, passed through a constructor' There is an array named `data` in the class. But since I used a constructor it works like this: `function __construct($data) // This data equals the class name
{ $this->data = $data;}` These are the first two lines of the radioStatus class. I'm adding it to the question as a extra bit of information.

Comment: $this->data, used in another file is, at most, an instance of an object, of a class... This is not a 'thing' and certainly not a 'class' now that this is out of our way, let's focus on the problem on hand. If $this->data is a instance, then var_dump it and see what you have in it, and post it as an edit, please.

Comment: @AresDraguna I used `var_dump` on it, this is what it returns:

`object(Data)#3 (1) { ["data"]=> array(6) { ["naam"]=> string(9) "Time" ["slogan"]=> string(17) "The time has come" ["stream_status"]=> NULL ["stream_titel"]=> NULL ["stream_luisteraars"]=> NULL ["stream_huidigNummer"]=> NULL } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please validate your parameter before trying to manipulate it:

```
<?php
class RadioStatus
{

    function __construct($data)
    {
        if (!($data instanceof Data)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('$data is not valid');
        }

        // we are safe now...
        $this->data = $data;
    }
}
```

you could also use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in this case:

```
function __construct(Data $data) { /** code... */ }
```